# Javascript MVC framework similar to Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Which Javascript MVC framework is closest in terms of concepts of routing, models, views and controllers to Asp.net MVC?

I have completed a personal project using the excelent [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) with [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) and have felt comfortable with Sammy due to its similarity to [Nancy](https://github.com/thecodejunkie/Nancy) the Micro .net framework.

I would like to convert this project to another Javascript MVC framework so I can have a comparision of strengths and weaknesses, I would like to choose one similar to Asp.net MVC but I am facing the [paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paradox_of_Choice%3a_Why_More_Is_Less) of [choice](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheBigGlossaryOfOpenSourceJavaScriptAndWebFrameworksWithCoolNames.aspx).

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/ is worth checking out

Comment: @Yasser - thanks, a bit of light reading to do

Answer (score 1):

[Source](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/)

There’s been a huge boom in the number of such MV* frameworks being released over the past few years.

[Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.com/), [Spine](http://spinejs.com/), [CanJS](http://canjs.us/) …

The list of new and stable solutions continues to grow each week and developers can quickly find themselves lost in a sea of options.

To help solve this problem, we created [TodoMVC](http://www.todomvc.com/) — a project which offers the same Todo application implemented in most of the popular JavaScript MV* frameworks of today
*— think of it as speed dating for frameworks.*

Solutions look and feel the same, have a common feature set, and make it easy for us to compare the syntax and structure of different frameworks, so we can select the one we feel the most comfortable with or at least, narrow down our choices.

[Journey Through The JavaScript MVC Jungle](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) is a must read for you.

Also visit [TodoMvc](http://www.todomvc.com/) - it will help you select an MV* framework.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer - as there are so many frameworks I haven't personally used - but I just wanted to share my experience and personal observations as I also came from  ASP.NET MVC and used a couple of these JS frameworks:

In general, I found them different from ASP.NET especially Controllers, the general tendency seems that models are smarter in JS frameworks, they tend to be controllers+models in ASP.NET terms. The other difference is probably that unlike ASP.NET MVC, there is always so many ways to do the same thing. Also unlike ASP.NET MVC, you'll often need other pieces to complement your framework choice, for example a routing library on top of knockout, a templating engine with backbone etc.. Finally, it is much more dynamic than ASP.NET, there are so many frameworks, evolving all the time, and it is very difficult to keep up to date or to find the definitive source of information (ps: there isn't any).

Yasser's resources are quiet good, also add [Addyosmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/) blog to your RSS feed, he knows his frameworks. ToDoMVC pointed out by Yasser is a great resource for having a quick idea about all the options and how things are done in different frameworks. It's a great starting point but it's just a starting point, you'll need to get your hands dirty to learn anything useful.

So I've used Backbone and Knockout.

**Backbone** is MVC but the C in backbone is collection rather than controller, it provides routing, underscore templating engine (but you can change it to whatever you want) and very handing Syncing with RESTful apis. It also uses underscore library which is by itself a great library to know about even if you decide that Backbone is not for you. Models - in backbone - are in the heart of the application, they are controllers+model in ASP.NET MVC terms.

> Models are the heart of any JavaScript application, containing the
>   interactive data as well as a large part of the logic surrounding it:
>   conversions, validations, computed properties, and access control.

**Knockout** is MVVM not MVC but still worth trying for a learning exercise, it only does model-binding, no routing, but it does it very elegantly.

Just pick one framework to try next, it's a learning exercise at the end. I'd go for Backbone *just* because it's quiet popular then try every single one of the other frameworks if I have the time. I bet it will be a very exciting exercise.

Comment: kabaros - thanks I was set on trying backbone and then angular.js seemed appealing which in turn prompted this question, I'll go for backbone first, and yeah all these javascript frameworks are exciting